# Transform an array with one element to an array with 2 elements

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of array: `["nice,start"]`. I want to transform this array in `["nice","start"]`, meaning in an array with 2 elements. How to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Is it always one element? Or is it N elements and you want to make 2N elements? Is there always one comma that you want to split at?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it but should work, flatmap works like map but flattens one level after the mapping (flattens == reduces array depth by one), split transform the string in an array of n strings depending on the value chosen

```js
["nice,start"].flatMap(el => el.split(","))
```

Long and easier to understand form

```js
const arr = ["nice,start"] // ["nice, start"]
const newArr = arr.map(el => el.split(",")) //  [["nice,"start"]]
newArr.flatten() // ["nice", "start"]
```

Alternatively, you can just take the element itself and split it (since it is an array with one element) which is more beginner friendly I guess

```js
const arr = ["nice,start"] // ["nice, start"]
const str = arr[0] //  "nice, start"
str.split(",") // ["nice", "start"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which helps to flatten the nested array and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to split the string into string array.

```js
let array = ["nice,start"];
let res = array.flatMap(element => element.split(','));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.reduce()` can work with combined `.split()` as the following:

```js
const data = ["nice,start"];
const result = data.reduce((a, c) => c.split(','), undefined);
console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ["nice,start"];
var newarr = arr[0].split(',');
console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

answer for given example:

```
var input = ["nice,start"];
if(input[0] !== undefined){
    console.log(input[0].split(","));
}
```

I added checking because I am used to do it all the time. Just to make sure it is not empty input;